# How to cd into the only subfolder by auto-completion in bash?

Tags: bash, centos, autocomplete

I am using Centos 7 and bash. I know on some machines, if there is only one subfolder (and some files) in current folder, when you type `cd <tab>` it will auto-complete the name of the subfolder. However, it doesn't work on my machine, although `<tab>` can do other auto-completion on my machine, e.g., `less ab<tab>` will auto-complete the filename starting with `ab`. How can I fix it?

Edit:

Another working machine has same Centos and bash. On my machine, `cd <tab>` does nothing but a beep. For `cd <tab><tab>`, it shows all files and the single subfolder in current folder. The single folders on both machine are proper (command `ls -ld the_single_folder` shows `drwxrwxr-x 2 user user ...`).

Some shell options (output of command `shopt`) are different. The output of `diff shoptA shoptB` is (my machine is B):

```
18c18
< extglob           on
---
> extglob           off
27c27
< hostcomplete      off
---
> hostcomplete      on
42a43
> syslog_history    off
```

I tried to change those different options (extglob and hostcomplete) on my machine using commands `shopt -s extglob` and `shopt -u hostcomplete`. But it didn't work

Command `complete -p cd` on that machine output `complete -o nospace -F _cd cd`, on my machine output `-bash: complete: cd: no completion specification`.

Command `type _cd` on that machine output:

```
_cd is a function
_cd () 
{ 
    local cur prev words cword;
    _init_completion || return;
    local IFS='
' i j k;
    compopt -o filenames;
    if [[ -z "${CDPATH:-}" || "$cur" == ?(.)?(.)/* ]]; then
        _filedir -d;
        return 0;
    fi;
    local -r mark_dirs=$(_rl_enabled mark-directories && echo y);
    local -r mark_symdirs=$(_rl_enabled mark-symlinked-directories && echo y);
    for i in ${CDPATH//:/'
'};
    do
        k="${#COMPREPLY[@]}";
        for j in $( compgen -d $i/$cur );
        do
            if [[ ( -n $mark_symdirs && -h $j || -n $mark_dirs && ! -h $j ) && ! -d ${j#$i/} ]]; then
                j+="/";
            fi;
            COMPREPLY[k++]=${j#$i/};
        done;
    done;
    _filedir -d;
    if [[ ${#COMPREPLY[@]} -eq 1 ]]; then
        i=${COMPREPLY[0]};
        if [[ "$i" == "$cur" && $i != "*/" ]]; then
            COMPREPLY[0]="${i}/";
        fi;
    fi;
    return 0
}
```

Comment: probably there's nothing to fix, and there's a good reason this is happening. What happens if you press `<tab><tab>`?

Comment: also, this might sound like a stupid question, but on these other machines, are you using the same bash? Or is it dash/zsh/something else? `echo $SHELL` might be a quick way of figuring out.

Comment: ```<tab><tab>``` showed all files and that subfolder on my machine, as most machines do. On another machine, it has same bash and Centos as shown by commands ```ps -p $$``` and ```cat /etc/os-release```. But it works well.

Comment: ok, so `cd <tab><tab>` in the folder you're expecting `cd <tab>` to work (but where it doesn't work) lists exactly one folder? Or none?

Comment: If there is only one subfolder in current folder, on the other machine, ```cd <tab>``` showed the only one subfolder. On my machine, it does nothing but a beep (```cd <tab><tab>``` shows all files and the single subfolder). For ```cd <tab><tab>```, if there are more than one subfolders in current folder, my machine shows all files and subfolders in current folder. But that machine shows only subfolders. It looks ```<tab>``` on that machine is smarter. Did I answer your question?

Comment: Let's focus on the case with only exactly one subfolder.

Comment: so, `ls -ld name_of_that_single_subfolder` tells you the permissions. Are they proper?

Comment: The command shows ```drwxrwxr-x 2 user user ...``` on both machines, which looks proper.

Comment: mysterious! We should probably start comparing shell options: `shopt > /tmp/shopt` on both machines, then copy over to one machine and compare using `diff shoptA shoptB`, maybe?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add all of the information you have given in the comments. Comments are hard to read, easy to miss and can be deleted without warning, so if you don't add the details to your question the information can be lost.

Comment: Take a look at output of `complete -p cd` on "*on some machines*".

Comment: I edited my post. Output of ```complete -p cd``` are different on both machines as shown in edited post. How can I make them same? I couldn't fully understand the man page of command ```complete```.

Comment: `_cd` is a function which is executed when you press "tab" after `cd `. See output of `type _cd`.

Comment: Yes you are right. ```_cd``` is a function (see edited post). Where should I put the code of the function?

Comment: I wonder if completions for `cd` come with `bash` or [you need extra package(s)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/264102/108618) maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [the link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/264102/bash-completion-is-very-incomplete-on-centos-7) in [@Kamil Maciorowski](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/108618/kamil-maciorowski) 's suggestion, I installed a package by command

```
yum --enablerepo=epel install bash-completion-extras
```

It solved my problem. Thank you all!